# inserting dynamic URL string in Attributes property

Tags: .net, vb.net, properties, attributes

I'm trying to get the url to appear in trackOutboundLink('') in the code below. I inherited this site and it's been a while since I messed with vb. Any advice would be appreciated. Thanks

```
        If DBReader("URL").ToString <> "" Then
            CustWebSite.NavigateUrl = DBReader("URL").ToString
            CustWebSite.ToolTip = DBReader("URL").ToString.Replace("http://", "")
            CustWebSite.Text = DBReader("URL").ToString.Replace("http://", "")
            CustWebSite.Attributes("onclick") = "trackOutboundLink(''); return false;"
            CustWebsiteDiv.Visible = True
        Else
            CustWebsiteDiv.Visible = False
        End If
```

The end result I'm looking for is :
http://www.testsite.com'); return false;" href="http://www.testsite.com">www.testsite.com

All works except for the url display in the

onclick="trackOutboundLink('http://www.testsite.com'); return false;"

section.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

String concatenation in VB.NET works the same as in C#.

`CustWebSite.Attributes("onclick") = String.Format("trackOutboundLink('{0}'); return false;", DBReader("URL"))`

Also, instead of making calls to `DBReader("URL")` multiple times, you would be better off storing the first call result in a local variable, and using that as required in all subsequent statements.